# android resources in apk

Tags: android, android-resources

In my android development project under the folder `res` there are all the resources my application uses. The size is 3.11 mb and contains 1013 files . On the other hand in the `apk` there is the folder `res` with all the resources as well , but this has a size of only 760 kb and contains only 332 files . Now does this means that not all the resources are packed? If this is the case what happens when a needed resources is referenced?

Comment: Are you referring to the release APK file or the debug one?

Answer (score 1):

> Now does this means that not all the
>   resources are packed ?

No, it means the APK file is a compressed ZIP-style archive.

Comment: I decompressed it before I checked this !

Comment: Also, bear in mind that many of the resource are pre-compiled in that `resources.arsc` file. Many of the XML ones should be treated this way, for example, converted into a binary XML format for smaller distribution and quicker on-device parsing. Do you have any proof that any resource you want is somehow unavailable to you on the device?

Comment: Not at all !, I was just surprised to find that less resources in the apk than in the res folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many of the XML ones are pre-compiled in tha resource.arsc file. You can use  aapt dump --values resources xxx.apk to view the resource.arsc file, and you will find that pre-compiled xml.